# Can I move my Mercurial working directory to another location?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am new to Mercurial and version control in general, so I'm sure this is a pretty basic question but I have, as yet, been unable to find the answer.

I am working on a small project which is under Mercurial version control.  The project and the .hg repository are currently on my local drive (C:\MyProject.hg), however I would like to move the whole lot to another location (in this case a network drive) which is backed up every night.  I would want this new location to become my working directory.

My question is, can I simply copy the MyProject directory (and hence the .hg repository) to the new location and have everything work as it did on my local drive?  Or does this via Mercurial commands (eg clone) so that Mercurial knows about the change of location?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a normal copy of the folder, but if you plan to continue using your local version, you should make the copy with the `hg clone`, so you can do a `hg pull` or `hg push` to sync the versions.  You can still push and pull if you don't use `hg clone` but it makes it a little easier.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* completely move your local version to a network drive and make that your new "local" version. You do **not** have to let mercurial know that its parent (project) directory is being moved.

As another answer mentioned however, it might be to your benefit to keep your project locally, and create another repository on the network drive (one that doesn't have a working directory) by cloning the one on your local machine to the networked drive. That way, you can keep your own repository locally and not have to change anything, while also getting to backup your repository on the network drive. You could setup a nightly cron job on either your machine (push) or on the network machine (pull) so that they remain in sync.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest option is to just move that folder to your network drive.  On your cloned working directory just update the paths found in the .hg/hgrc file (located in the .hg/ folder if that wasn't clear.  In your cloned repo you will see a default path like this...

```
[paths]
default = c:\MyProject
```

That path should be changed to your new location.  Also if there is another path you can add another like this...

```
[paths]
default = c:\MyProject
Bitbucket = https://user@bitbucket.org/MyProject
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys.  It is as I suspected that I could just copy the directory.  Also, I was unaware of the need to update the default path so thanks andy9d!

Comment: UPDATE: I have just searched for .hg/hgrc file in the .hg folder and I dont seem to have it.  Are there any other locations that this file could be stored?

Comment: If the file isn't there, create it. When you clone a repository, it is created for you and the default path added, but it won't exist by default on a new repo. Also, +1 for mentioning the paths item in the hgrc file... I often use this to set a new push destination.